# Select COUNT in DB::raw and 2 tables

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables:

**category:**

```
idCat, nameCat, urlCat
```

**detailpost:**

```
idDetailPost, nameDetailPost, viewDetailPost, idCat
```

It's mean 1 category have many posts. And my issue is: I need a table on website have:

```
nameCat 
urlCat 
count(post in category)
count(viewDetailPost)
```

[image: Table]

This is SQL right. I tested it in XAMPP:

```
SELECT
     c.nameCat AS nameCategory,
     c.urlCat AS urlCategory,
     COUNT(d.idCat) AS countPost,
     COUNT(d.viewDetailPost) AS viewPost FROM
     category c,
     detailpost d WHERE
     c.idCat = d.idCat GROUP BY
     d.idCat
```

But I don't know how to write it in Laravel 5.4. I tried DB::raw, DB::select, join... Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('detailpost as dp')
->leftJoin('category as c','c.id','=','dp.idCat')
->select( 'c.nameCat AS nameCategory', 'c.urlCat AS urlCategory',DB::raw('count(dp.idCat) as countPost),DB::raw('count(dp.viewDetailPost) as viewPost ))
->groupBy('dp.idCat')
->get();
```

Comment: I copy it and error: syntax error, unexpected 'AS' (T_AS), expecting ',' or ')'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! This is answer!

```
$sql =  DB::table('detailpost')
            ->select(
                'category.nameCat AS name_category',
                'category.urlCat AS url_category' ,
                DB::raw('count(detailpost.idCat) as count_post'),
                DB::raw('count(detailpost.viewDetailPost) as view_post')
            )
            ->leftJoin('category','detailpost.idCat','category.idCat')
            ->groupBy('category.nameCat', 'category.urlCat')
            ->orderBy('detailpost.idCat', 'ASC')
            ->get();
```

[blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeMk3.png)

[Website's table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYtik.png)